# instance has no attribute (python)

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I have a weird issue, which is probably easy to resolve.

I have a class Database with an `__init__` and an `executeDictMore` method (among others).

```
class Database():
    def __init__(self, database, server,login, password ):
        self.database = database
        my_conv = { FIELD_TYPE.LONG: int }
        self.conn = MySQLdb.Connection(user=login, passwd=password, db=self.database, host=server, conv=my_conv)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def executeDictMore(self, query):
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()
        if data == None :
            return None
        result = []
        for d in data:
            desc = self.cursor.description
            dict = {}
            for (name, value) in zip(desc, d) :
                dict[name[0]] = value
            result.append(dict)
        return result
```

Then I instantiate this class in a file db_functions.py :

```
from Database import Database
db = Database()
```

And I call the executeDictMore method from a function of db_functions :

```
def test(id):
    query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_id=%s;" %(id)
    return db.executeDictMore(query)
```

Now comes the weird part.
If I import db_functions and call db_functions.test(id) from a python console:

```
import db_functions
t = db_functions.test(12)
```

it works just fine.
But if I do the same thing from another python file I get the following error :

```
AttributeError: Database instance has no attribute 'executeDictMore'
```

I really don't understand what is going on here. I don't think I have another Database class interfering. And I append the folder where the modules are in sys.path, so it should call the right module anyway.

If someone has an idea, it's very welcome.

Comment: Can you please post the code of "from another python file" so we can see how you utelize the `db` instance? Can I assume you're importing `Database.py` multiple times? In that case there could be an issue where db is already defined in the global scope and cause some shady issues. (just brainstorming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another `Database` module or package in your path somewhere, and it is getting imported instead.

To diagnose where that other module is living, add:

```
import Database
print Database.__file__
```

before the `from Database import Database` line; it'll print the filename of the module. You'll have to rename one or the other module to not conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert (not append) into your `sys.path` if you want it first in the search path:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/your/Database/class')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could at least try to avoid SQL injection. Python provides such neat ways to do so:

```
def executeDictMore(self, query, data=None):
    self.cursor.execute(query, data)
```

and

```
def test(id):
    query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_id=%s"
    return db.executeDictMore(query, id)
```

are the ways to do so.

Sorry, this should rather be a comment, but an answer allows for better formatting. Iam aware that it doesn't answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure what is wrong but you could try passing the database object to the function as an argument like
`db_functions.test(db, 12)` with db being your Database class

Comment: I thought of this too, but you shouldn't need to because once imported and instanciated the `db` object should be accessible from any module importing the `Database.py` file and accessing the `db` object.